# Mass disable jenkins jobs

Tags: hudson, jenkins

Is it possible to disable a large number of Jenkins jobs in one go?
I have a large number of jenkins job I need to disable. Visiting each job in turn and disbling is tedious.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin

That works beautifully install it go to http://your_jenkins.com:8080/slicing/jobdisabledbool/?

Comment: The plugin doesn't show ALL the jobs though. I have jobs in folders that are NOT shown.

Answer (score 0):

By using configuration slicing plugin:

By using this plugin easy to find out anything has enabled or disable jobs and timer separated jobs

Manage Jenkins >Config slicing > select options